# Which cointegration test to apply when variables are I(1) and I(2)?

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I am working on a 35 sample size data time series, and after applying ADF and PP test two of my variables are integrated of order 1 I(1) and one is integrated I(2). Which cointegration approach should I apply before testing for causality between the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which cointegration test to apply when variables are I(1) and I(2)?

The series that is I(2) cannot cointegrate with the other two series because at least two series need to have the highest order of integration (here it is 2) for cointegration among all series to be possible. Meanwhile, the first difference of the I(2) series may or may not be cointegrated with the other two series, and that can be tested with Johansen test, for example.

> Which cointegration approach should I apply before testing for causality between the variables?

Use the Toda-Yamamoto procedure as described in David Giles' blog post ["Testing for Granger Causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html). No cointegration approach is needed; note point 7: *No matter what you conclude about cointegration at Step 6, this is not going to affect what follows*.